# JDK 19 not being recognised in VSCode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, java-19

I have a grade project (7.6) that is also a LibGDX project and the latest java jdk (19.0.1) installed. I am on Mac OS Monterey btw.
The problem is that when opening the gradle project inside VSCode it throws a lot of errors.
It is however possible to run the program using the `gradle run` command.
Here are some examples of the errors that it throws:

```
Method references are allowed only at source level 1.8 or above
Syntax error on token "record", @ expected
Syntax error on token "double", { expected
Syntax error on tokens, ClassHeader expected instead
Syntax error on tokens, ClassInstanceCreationExpressionName expected instead
```

Here are the things that I have already tried to fix it:

1. Set the `JAVA_HOME` variable to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home`
2. Set `java.jdt.ls.java.home` to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home` in the user and workspace section of the VSCode settings
3. Switch the "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" VSCode extension to the pre-release version
4. Clean and reload the Java Language Server Workspace

Unfortunately without any success. At this point I'm clueless as to what else to try because it does work without problems with gradle, it's just inside VSCode that it shows all these errors.
Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Configure the `java.configuration.runtimes` property in your user settings.

Press ⌘ + ⇧ + P (Command + Shift + P) and select `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` from the list. Insert the following settings between the first `{` and the last `}`.

```
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-1.8",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-8",
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-11",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-11",
  },
  {
    "name": "JavaSE-19",
    "path": "/path/to/jdk-19",
    "default": true
  },
]
```

If you do not have multiple versions of Java in your system, remove all but the last one (i.e. jdk-19). In any case, make sure `"default": true` is there for jdk-19.

### Alternatively,

Press ⌘ + ⇧ + P and select `Java: Configure Java Runtime` from the list. Edit the value of `Java Version` on the resulting page.

Comment: Hello thank you for your answer!  I set the `java.configuration.runtime` according to your comment and set the path to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-19.jdk/Contents/Home`. However, unfortunately the errors persisted even after reloading the workspace and restarting VSCode. I also tried you alternative answer and set the two listed java versions to `19` but then I received the following error: `Unsupported class file major version 63`

Comment: @Rango - Set `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-bin.zip` in gradle-wrapper.properties of your project. Also, make sure the same version is referenced in build.gradle file. Also, the build.gradle file should have jdk version 19 (e.g. `sourceCompatibility = '19'`).